# Manipulate a graph from data

Tags: plotting, manipulate, data

I want to manipulate some data, to do this i create a graph.
But i don´t know how to manipulate the data.

```
SetDirectory["D:\\Documents and Settings\\Física\\Desktop\\Mesa Giratória_com \base"];
dados2 = Import["Dados_Rotacao.txt", "Table"]
Manipulate [ListLinePlot[{dados2, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Dashed, Red}, 
  PlotLabel -> "Gráfico no Eixo X (Visão Vertical)",
  AxesLabel -> {"Posição em x", "Posição em y"}}],dados2,0,20]
```

Comment: I tried running your code but I got `SetDirectory::cdir: "Cannot set current directory to ...` and  `Import::nffil: File not found during Import. >>` Pls. help me.

Comment: The data is in a pen drive.

Comment: But i can copy here
-1.73 24.685
-2.527 23.078
-2.395 21.762
-2.569 20.091
-2.55 18.775
-2.298 17.425
-1.974 16.115
-1.483 15.027
-0.941 14.083
-0.272 13.235
0.434 12.565
1.261 11.881
2.083 11.359
2.936 10.966
3.799 10.72
4.55 10.509
5.403 10.448
6.317 10.583
7.168 10.735
8.022 11.071
8.801 11.475
9.577 12.026
10.239 12.626
10.869 13.35
11.496 14.099
12.11 14.964
12.618 15.874
13.033 16.902
13.511 17.916
13.887 18.892

Comment: Its a table with pair of data. 
{-1.73     ;   24,685}
{-2.527    ;  23.078}
....... and on

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
dados2 = {{-1.73, 24.685}, {-2.527, 23.078}, {-2.395, 
   21.762}, {-2.569, 20.091}, {-2.55, 18.775}, {-2.298, 
   17.425}, {-1.974, 16.115}, {-1.483, 15.027}, {-0.941, 
   14.083}, {-0.272, 13.235}, {0.434, 12.565}, {1.261, 
   11.881}, {2.083, 11.359}, {2.936, 10.966}, {3.799, 10.72}, {4.55, 
   10.509}, {5.403, 10.448}, {6.317, 10.583}, {7.168, 10.735}, {8.022,
    11.071}, {8.801, 11.475}, {9.577, 12.026}, {10.239, 
   12.626}, {10.869, 13.35}, {11.496, 14.099}, {12.11, 
   14.964}, {12.618, 15.874}, {13.033, 16.902}, {13.511, 
   17.916}, {13.887, 18.892}}

(* edited in response to query *)
Manipulate[Module[{
   data = dados2[[;; n]],
   plotrange = {Floor@Min[#], Ceiling@Max[#]} & /@ Transpose@dados2
   },
  ListLinePlot[data,
   PlotStyle -> {Thick, Dashed, Red},
   PlotLabel -> "Gráfico no Eixo X (Visão Vertical)",
   AxesLabel -> {"Posição em x", "Posição em y"},
   PlotRange -> plotrange,
   Epilog -> Disk[Last@data, 0.2]]
  ],
 {n, 2, Length[dados2], 1}]
```

Comment: It works! Thanks

Comment: Is there somehow to put while the graph is plot a point following the dashes, like a little ball making that path?

Comment: See edit for a simple (but crude) approach.